# Silex Twig app.request global not working

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

I am currently working with Silex and Twig, and I am encountering an issue where the

```
{{ app.request }}
```

call does not return anything.

Here is my twig configuration

```
'twig' => $application->share($application->extend('twig', function (Twig_Environment $twig, Application $application) {
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/../../src/quest/view');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
    $host = $application['request']->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
    $path = $application['request']->getPathInfo();

    $twig->addGlobal('RESOURCE', '/web/res');
    $twig->addGlobal('HOST', $host);
    $twig->addGlobal('PATH', $path);

    return $twig;
}))
```

My variable is named 'application' instead of 'app', but I also tried

```
{{ app.request.host }}
{{ application.request.host }}
```

and neither of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're overwriting `$app["twig"]` entirely instead of using the one created by TwigServiceProvider. Note that it registers the `app` global ([link](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/TwigServiceProvider.php#L48)) that you'll need to do yourself on your `Twig_Environment` instance.

Comment: ok, understood, I didn't know if was added by default as a global like that, after I added it back to global it works now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when you use render other controller.